Do I need a new weatherhead or conduit for my heavy-up?
In the ongoing saga of my electric renovation (NEC 2023, Dayton Ohio jurisdiction), I'm nearing the time for a rough-in inspection.  I'm finally ready to run the 4/0-4/0-4/0 SEU along the outside of my house, and I want to check a couple things before I start spending money.


Above, I've attached a picture of my current service connection/power drop/hookup.  It looks... old and bad to me.  I can run the new cable to this same spot for the utility company to hook it up, but I'd like to verify it's actually OK to leave it as-is.  Is it up to code?  Is the utility company going to look at it and say "nope, need a new one"?

Right now the current 100A 2AWG cable is just hanging out, clamped occasionally, along the outside/brick of the house.  I'd plan on following a similar route with new cable.  My understanding is that I don't need conduit - is that correct?  If that is correct, what is typically used at the top of a meter (or, in my case, a meter-main) to allow the cable in without water ingress?  Looking at my current meter, it looks like the answer is mostly "a whole bunch of silicone caulking."  Is that typical?



Check with your local inspector what they allow.  Cable usually does not need conduit/protection above 8ft.  Below 8ft it needs protection, inside a wall, conduit, a box(wood/plastic/metal) covering it.

Who is your electric utility?

@ThreePhaseEel AES-Ohio.

That would be a relatively minor part of the costs, and the electrician who does the work (and certainly the inspector) should make sure the right thing is done. Why are you worrying about this detail?

@keshlam Primarily because I am not an electrician, but I am the one doing the work.

The answer to your first question is governed by your utility's rules
Generally speaking, as long as a service entrance is securely attached to the building (NEC 230.51), has some form of weatherhead or gooseneck (NEC 230.54), and uses a wiring means permitted by NEC 230.43, the NEC has no quarrel with it.  However, individual electric utilities are free to set more strict rules on service entrances in their territory.
The good news is that AES-Ohio, in their service handbook, does permit a 200A or smaller service to be run to an on-building termination without a conduit and mast, as per drawing SH-11-001 on page 39 of the PDF.  So, that answers your first question: you are clear to replicate the existing setup with 4/0 SE cable and a suitable weatherhead when doing your heavy-up.
As to getting the SE cable into the meter box...
The main problem with running a service entrance using SE cable is getting it into the top of the meter socket.  This is done using a SE cable gland fitting -- Arlington makes a suitable one in their WTC210, but I'm sure other manufacturers have equivalents.  However, it may still require some help getting a good, watertight seal, especially since it likely has to be threaded into the hub fitting atop the box, which is not exactly a use case that it was designed for.
I personally would be asking the utility if I could bring the SE cable around and into the bottom of the meter socket, similar to where an underground service enters the socket.  This way, you get a nice drip loop that keeps water out of the the meter socket box.  It also spares the trouble of trying to mate a SE cable gland connector to a hub fitting.

Would the existing building terminations be reusable, or should they be replaced?

The "termination" in question was the "clevis," and the handbook you linked (thank you!) says AES will provide that, and a new weatherhead is like $15 so I'm just gunna get new ones.

Sorry to come back to this so much later; but I've got the gland for the top that fits the 4/0-4/0-4/0 SEU really well, but I can't seem to find gaskets/glands that will fit the 4/0-4/0-4/0-2/0 SER cable shape well.  Do people not typically have a gland on the bottom for the feed-through power?

@user112697 I take it the SER cable is for a feeder that exits the main panel?

That's correct.

@user112697 -- also, I take it the utility requires the SEU for the service to come in from the top?

Yes, that's also correct.  Technically I could shell out a few grand to get them to convert it to an underground service, but if I'm not willing to do that they're not OK with it looping around to the underside (I specifically asked, and was specifically rejected).
